# How to eliminate duplicate XML nodes using C# code

Tags: c#, xml, linq, duplicates, element

I have a schema XML file, that contains nodes for Table, Columns and ForeignKeys like shown below.

```
<Table schema="Reports_vN" name="pstpyr" caption="PR Payroll Posting">
    <Column name="recnum" alias="Record Number" isprimarykey="1" />
    <Column name="pstnum" alias="Posting Number" />    
</Table>
<Table schema="Reports_vN" name="payrec" caption="PR Payroll Record">
    <Column name="recnum" alias="Record Number" isprimarykey="1" />
    <Column name="empnum" alias="Employee" />
    <Column name="strprd" alias="Period Start" />
    <ForeignKey pkSchema="Reports_vN" pkTable="payrec" fkSchema="Reports_vN" fkTable="tmcdln" name="Record Number">
        <ForeignKeyCol pkCol="recnum" fkCol="recnum" />
    </ForeignKey>
    <ForeignKey pkSchema="Reports_vN" pkTable="payrec" fkSchema="Reports_vN" fkTable="jobcst" name="Payroll Number">
        <ForeignKeyCol pkCol="recnum" fkCol="payrec" />
    </ForeignKey>
    <ForeignKey pkSchema="Reports_vN" pkTable="payrec" fkSchema="Reports_vN" fkTable="jobcst" name="Payroll Number">
        <ForeignKeyCol pkCol="recnum" fkCol="payrec" />
    </ForeignKey>
</Table>
```

So like observed above it contains duplicate  elements (last two foreign keys). I'm new to LINQ. Can someone please share a sample using which I can remove this duplicate element from the XML file.

Comment: First of all, your `XML` isn't well-formatted. You have multiple root nodes which is illegal. The `<Table>` nodes should be housed under one root node.

Then, you haven't quite defined what a _duplicate_ node is. Is it merely any nodes that comes after the first one by its name alone, _in the order_ it appears in your `XML` file? Or otherwise do all attributes and sub-nodes also have to be the same for it to be identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `XML` isn't well-formatted. You have multiple root nodes which is illegal. The `<Table>` nodes should be housed under one root node.

Then, you haven't quite defined what a *duplicate* node is. Is it merely duplicates going by the node name alone? Or do the nodes sub-nodes and attributes too have to be the same?

### 1. Duplicates by Node (Element) Name Only

This is easy. You get all elements by that name, then do a `Skip(1)` to *skip* the first, and remove the rest.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
xDoc.Root.Descendants("ForeignKey").Skip(1).Remove();
```

Now the `XML` looks like this:

```
<MyRoot>
  <Table schema="Reports_vN" name="pstpyr" caption="PR Payroll Posting">
    <Column name="recnum" alias="Record Number" isprimarykey="1" />
    <Column name="pstnum" alias="Posting Number" />
  </Table>
  <Table schema="Reports_vN" name="payrec" caption="PR Payroll Record">
    <Column name="recnum" alias="Record Number" isprimarykey="1" />
    <Column name="empnum" alias="Employee" />
    <Column name="strprd" alias="Period Start" />
    <ForeignKey pkSchema="Reports_vN" pkTable="payrec" fkSchema="Reports_vN" fkTable="tmcdln" name="Record Number">
      <ForeignKeyCol pkCol="recnum" fkCol="recnum" />
    </ForeignKey>
  </Table>
</MyRoot>
```

### 2. Thorough Check including Child Elements and Attributes

I say, your best bet is to use `Deserialization`. First you'll need to create a set of classes that match your `XML` format. It would look like this depending on your provided `XML`. Note that I added a _root node, named `MyRoot`.

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot")]
public class MyRoot
{
    [XmlElement("Table")]
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    [XmlAttribute("schema")]
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("caption")]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Column")]
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ForeignKey")]
    public List<ForeignKey> ForeignKeys { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("alias")]
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("isprimarykey")]
    public string IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class ForeignKey
{
    [XmlAttribute("pkSchema")]
    public string PkSchema { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("pkTable")]
    public string PkTable { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("fkSchema")]
    public string FkSchema { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("fkTable")]
    public string FkTable { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ForeignKeyCol")]
    public ForeignKeyCol ForeignKeyCol { get; set; }
}

public class ForeignKeyCol
{
    [XmlAttribute("pkCol")]
    public string PkCol { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("fkCol")]
    public string FkCol { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can use the following method to deserialize your `XML`.

```
public static T DeserializeXMLFileToObject<T>(string XmlFilename)
{
    T returnObject = default(T);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlFilename)) return default(T);

    try
    {
        StreamReader xmlStream = new StreamReader(XmlFilename);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        returnObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return returnObject;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
MyRoot xml = DeserializeXMLFileToObject<MyRoot>("data.xml");
```

Now it's a matter of using simple `C#` technique to finding and removing duplicates. Easiest would be to write a `Comparer` so you can easily compare multiple objects.